# How to publish AutoML(Firebase) model with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-automl, automl, firebase-machine-learning

how can I publish the model not using the firebase UI but using the code?
I'm already create a client witch fill and predicts my model using node.js. And from my client application I'm receiving my model by name like this:

```
 let remoteModel = AutoMLImageLabelerRemoteModel(
       // name: "training_model"  // The name you assigned in
        name:"v20201209133002"
        // the Firebase console.
    )
...
if (ModelManager.modelManager().isModelDownloaded(remoteModel)) {
            options = AutoMLImageLabelerOptions(remoteModel: remoteModel)
            options!.confidenceThreshold = NSNumber(value: PRECOGNITION_PERSENTAGE)
            self.imageLabeler = ImageLabeler.imageLabeler(options: options!)
            onSuccess()
        } else {
...
```

From firebase UI to publish already trained model I can do something like:

[image]
[image]

But how can I do the same with node or phyton? Any help?